# TERADATA Stored Procedure return data error

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I created a procedure that does these steps:

1. Deletes the last 8 days fro the historic table
2. Then we add back the updated data of the last 8 days to the historic table
3. Returns all the data of the historic table

When I add the last step (number 3), I get an error shown in the screenshot below. Can you please help me understand what I should fix to make this work?

[image]

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_New_Procedure ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
SQL SECURITY OWNER

BEGIN 
------------Deleting last 8 days of data -------------------------------

   DELETE FROM History_Table
        WHERE Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -INTERVAL '8' DAY(FORMAT 'YYYYMMdd') 
                        AND CURRENT_DATE -INTERVAL '1' DAY(FORMAT 'YYYYMMdd');

------------Inserting updated last 8 days of data------------------------

   INSERT INTO History_Table
   SELECT
      FinalTable.*
   FROM
      Data_Query AS FinalTable;


 ------------Return All values from updated History_Table-------------------

     SELECT * FROM History_Table;

END;
```

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Teradata follows Standard SQL, you must use cursor syntax (it's not an actual cursor  which should avoided for processing data) to return result sets. Without cursor you can only return a single row INTO variables.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_New_Procedure ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
SQL SECURITY OWNER

BEGIN 
------------Deleting last 8 days of data -------------------------------

   DELETE FROM History_Table
        WHERE Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 1 
                       AND CURRENT_DATE - 8

------------Inserting updated last 8 days of data------------------------

   INSERT INTO History_Table
   SELECT
      FinalTable.*
   FROM
      Data_Query AS FinalTable;


 ------------Return All values from updated History_Table-------------------

   BEGIN
      DECLARE cur CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR
      SELECT * FROM History_Table;

      OPEN cur; -- don't close it, otherwise there's no result
   END;

END;
```

Hopefully `History_Table` is partitioned by that date column.